# Telethon Как узнать, отправлял ли пользователь сообщение

Tags: python, парсер, telethon

Есть группа около 2500 человек, нужно спарсить всех пользователей, которые отправляли сообщение в группу за последний месяц. Делаю через Python Telethon. Написал код, рабочий, но возвращает только одного меня, на остальных не реагирует, а точнее отправляет подобное:

У меня: `[Message(id=363322, peer_id=PeerUser(user_id=504679753), date=datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 11, 47, 59, ...]`

Другие участники: `[, total=0]`

Мой код выглядит так:

```
async def dump_users(chat, client: TelegramClient):
    offset = 0

    chat_object = InputChannel(chat['chat_id'], chat['access_hash'])
    all_participants = []
    while True:
        
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(chat_object, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit, hash=0))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        
        all_participants.extend(participants.users)
        offset += len(participants.users)

    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(all_participants)).start()
    
    all_user_details = []
    times = 0
    for participant in all_participants:
        times += 1
        
        status = participant.status
        
        if isinstance(status, UserStatusOffline):
            user_status = datetime.datetime.strftime(participant.status.was_online, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusOnline):
            user_status = datetime.datetime.strftime(participant.status.expires, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusRecently):
            user_status = 'Недавно'
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusLastWeek):
            user_status = 'На прошлой неделе'
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusLastMonth):
            user_status = 'В прошлом месяце'
        else:
            user_status = 'Не указано'
        
        message = False
        one_month_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        messages = await client.get_messages(participant, limit=1, offset_date=one_month_ago)
        print(messages)
        
        if messages:
            message = True
            
        info = {
                    "id": participant.id, 
                    "first_name": participant.first_name, 
                    "user": participant.username, 
                    "phone": participant.phone, 
                    "status": user_status,
                    "premium": participant.premium,
                    "message": message
                }
        
        all_user_details.append(info)    
        bar.update(times)   
    
    with open(json_file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(all_user_details, outfile)

    bar.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так, теперь работает правильно, но парсим последние 5к сообщений, если кто подскажет, как парсить за последние 30 дней, буду благодарен.

Код:

```
async def dump_users(chat, client: TelegramClient):
    offset = 0

    # Получаем участников чата
    chat_object = InputChannel(chat['chat_id'], chat['access_hash'])
    all_participants = []
    while True:
        
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(chat_object, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit, hash=0))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        
        all_participants.extend(participants.users)
        offset += len(participants.users)

    # Парсим тех, кто отправлял сообщения отдельно
    limit_messages = 5000 
    bar_times = 0
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(all_participants) + limit_messages).start()
    
    active_participants = []
    async for message in client.iter_messages(chat_object, limit=limit_messages):
        bar_times += 1
        bar.update(bar_times) 
        sender_id = message.sender_id
        if sender_id not in active_participants:
            active_participants.append(sender_id)
    
    # Парсим всех и вся и записываем данные в json файл 
    all_user_details = []
    for participant in all_participants:
        bar_times += 1
        
        status = participant.status
        message = True if participant.id in active_participants else False
        
        if isinstance(status, UserStatusOffline):
            user_status = datetime.datetime.strftime(participant.status.was_online, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusOnline):
            user_status = datetime.datetime.strftime(participant.status.expires, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusRecently):
            user_status = 'Недавно'
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusLastWeek):
            user_status = 'На прошлой неделе'
        elif isinstance(status, UserStatusLastMonth):
            user_status = 'В прошлом месяце'
        else:
            user_status = 'Не указано'
        
            
        info = {
                    "id": participant.id, 
                    "first_name": participant.first_name, 
                    "user": participant.username, 
                    "phone": participant.phone, 
                    "status": user_status,
                    "premium": participant.premium,
                    "message": message
                }
        
        all_user_details.append(info)    
        bar.update(bar_times)   
    
    with open(json_file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(all_user_details, outfile)

    bar.finish()
```